# How to get data of second data frame for all values of particular columns values matched in first dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Have two dataframe as below

```
first_df
 |-- company_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- max_dd: date (nullable = true)
 |-- min_dd: date (nullable = true)
 |-- mean: double (nullable = true)
 |-- count: long (nullable = false)

second_df 
 |-- company_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- max_dd: date (nullable = true)
 |-- mean: double (nullable = true)
 |-- count: long (nullable = false)
```

I have some companies data in second_df . I need to get data from second_df for those company ids which are listed in first_df.

what kind of spark apis useful here for me ?
How can i do it ?

Thank you.

**Question extension :**

If there is no stored records then first_df would be empty. Hence first_df("mean") & first_df("count") would be null resulting "acc_new_mean" is null. In that case I need to set "new_mean" as second_df("mean") , how to do it ?
I tried like this but it is not working 
Any clue how to handle here .withColumn("new_mean", ... ) ???

```
val acc_new_mean = (second_df("mean") + first_df("mean")) / (second_df("count") + first_df("count"))
    val acc_new_count  =  second_df("count") + first_df("count")


    val new_df = second_df.join(first_df.withColumnRenamed("company_id", "right_company_id").as("a"), 
                                 (  $"a.right_company_id"  === second_df("company_id") && ( second_df("min_dd")  > $"a.max_dd" ) ) 
                            , "leftOuter")
                            .withColumn("new_mean", if(acc_new_mean == null) lit(second_df("mean")) else  acc_new_mean )
```

Comment: @summerbulb any help/suggestion please?

Comment: @dytyniak any help/suggestion please?

Comment: @jezrael any help/suggestion please?

Comment: Can you add some example? It seems both the dataframe are same and It depends on what data you want. You can either join or combine both dataframe with the union.

Comment: Please provide examples of data and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 val acc_new_mean = //new mean literaal
 val acc_new_count  =   //new count literaal


          val resultDf = computed_df.join(accumulated_results_df.as("a"), 
                             (  $"company_id"  === computed_df("company_id")  ) 
                        , "leftOuter")
                        .withColumn("new_mean", when( acc_new_mean.isNull,lit(computed_df("mean")) ).otherwise(acc_new_mean) )
                        .withColumn("new_count", when( acc_new_count.isNull,lit(computed_df("count")) ).otherwise(acc_new_count) )
                         .select(
                            computed_df("company_id"),
                            computed_df("max_dd"),
                            col("new_mean").as("mean"),
                            col("new_count").as("count")
                          )
```

Answer (score 2):

**APPROACH 1 :**

If you are finding difficult to join 2 dataframes using the dataframe's join API, you could use sql if you are comfortable in sql. For that you can register your 2 dataframes as tables in the spark memory and the write sql on top of that.

```
second_df.registerTempTable("table_second_df")
first_df.registerTempTable("table_first_df")

val new_df = spark.sql("select distinct s.* from table_second_df s join table_first_df f on s.company_id=f.company_id")
new_df.show()
```

As you requested, I have added the logic.

Consider your `first_df` looks like below :

```
+----------+----------+----------+----+-----+
|company_id|    max_dd|    min_dd|mean|count|
+----------+----------+----------+----+-----+
|         A|2019-04-05|2019-04-01|  10|  100|
|         A|2019-04-06|2019-04-02|  20|  200|
|         B|2019-04-08|2019-04-01|  30|  300|
|         B|2019-04-09|2019-04-02|  40|  400|
+----------+----------+----------+----+-----+
```

Consider your `second_df` looks like below :

```
+----------+----------+----+-----+
|company_id|    max_dd|mean|count|
+----------+----------+----+-----+
|         A|2019-04-03|  10|  100|
|         A|2019-04-02|  20|  200|
+----------+----------+----+-----+
```

Since company id `A` is there in the second table, I have taken the latest `max_dd` record from `second_df`. For company id `B`, it is not in `second_df` I took the latest `max_dd` record from `first_df`.

Please find the code below.

```
first_df.registerTempTable("table_first_df")
second_df.registerTempTable("table_second_df")
val new_df = spark.sql("select company_id,max_dd,min_dd,mean,count from (select distinct s.company_id,s.max_dd,null as min_dd,s.mean,s.count,row_number() over (partition by s.company_id order by s.max_dd desc) rno from table_second_df s join table_first_df f on s.company_id=f.company_id) where rno=1 union select company_id,max_dd,min_dd,mean,count from (select distinct f.*,row_number() over (partition by f.company_id order by f.max_dd desc) rno from table_first_df f left join table_second_df s  on s.company_id=f.company_id where s.company_id is null) where rno=1")
new_df.show()
```

Below is the result :

[image]

**APPROACH 2 :**

Instead of creating a temp table as I mentioned in `Approach 1`, you can use the `join` of `dataframe's` API. This is the same logic in `Approach 1` but here I am using `dataframe's` API to accomplish this. Please don't forget to import `org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window` as I have used `Window.patitionBy` in the below code.

```
val new_df = second_df.as('s).join(first_df.as('f),$"s.company_id" === $"f.company_id","inner").drop($"min_dd").withColumn("min_dd",lit("")).select($"s.company_id", $"s.max_dd",$"min_dd", $"s.mean", $"s.count").dropDuplicates.withColumn("Rno", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy($"s.company_id").orderBy($"s.max_dd".desc))).filter($"Rno" === 1).drop($"Rno").union(first_df.as('f).join(second_df.as('s),$"s.company_id" === $"f.company_id","left_anti").select($"f.company_id", $"f.max_dd",$"f.min_dd", $"f.mean", $"f.count").dropDuplicates.withColumn("Rno", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy($"f.company_id").orderBy($"f.max_dd".desc))).filter($"Rno" === 1).drop($"Rno"))
new_df.show()
```

Below is the result :

[image]

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: thanks Sarath , but if there is no match found I need to take values from first_df only ... if found from new_df , how can it be done? in spark API

Comment: second_df comes from Cassandra , where multiple entires possible for each company_id , i need to pick only lastest entry present.  if no entry then i need to take first_df column values

Comment: thank you , may I know what is this "left_anti" ? 
    in    first_df.as('f).join(second_df.as('s),$"s.company_id" === $"f.company_id","left_anti") ?

Comment: Left_anti selects the data from first_df where those company ids are not there in second_df. If the solution works please mark the answer as accepted @Shyam

Comment: giving error org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`f.min_dd`' given input columns: [f.company_id, f.max_dd, f.count, f.mean];;

Comment: can you please look at "Question extension " in edited question please

Comment: can you please check if you can access this notebook ... https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/1165111237342523/2433978462046791/7035720262824085/latest.html